# Generate the item values of a constant array of integer logarithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, c-preprocessor

I cannot seem to understand this piece of code written in c++:

```
static const char LogTable256[256] = 
{
 #define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
 -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
 LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

how can I generate the same array using loops?

Comment: You copy this much code into an empty file & run (if available) this command, "`g++ -E file.cpp > file_preprocessed.cpp`", you may see that the `LT(n)` macro would have replaced it with 16 n-s at every instance. It seems that, someone is storing `char` with such ascii based values. With loops, there is no systematic way to generate this sequence, hence it's better left as above.

Comment: LT(n) will be replaces by value n 8 times for each. so you can simply use for loops for i>4 ; better you try it yourself and show us your progress

Comment: @RamandeepPunia 16 times, actually. You'll end up with -1, then a list of 255 values where you'll always find 2^n instances of n for n from 0 through 7.

Comment: @TinyT , Yes, your are right. its 16 times. Somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#define` lines can appear anywhere in your code as long their usage follow them. Since they are preprocessor directives, there is no difference between:

```
static const char LogTable256[256] = 
{
 #define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
 -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
 LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

and

```
#define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n

static const char LogTable256[256] = 
{
 -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
 LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};
```

If the second one makes sense to you, then rest assured that the first is just as good as far as the compiler and behavior of the program is concerned. The first one could mislead human readers to think that the macro is defined in the scope of the declaration of the variable, which is not true.

Comment: "the first is just as good", no, it isn't. It hides the macro definition within other text, and it indicates that the programmer mistakenly thinks a macro is limited to the scope it is defined it. Source code is about communicating to humans.

Comment: @RSahu This has helped me understand how the array has been created but I also need to reproduce the same code in python and i dont know how that would be done.

Comment: @MuhammadAliQadri, as far as I know, python does not have anything analogous to C preprocessor. However, python is a dynamic language. You can, most likely, pull off what you want to do. Feel free to ask another question with all the details.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I generate the same array using loops?

You can't do that using loops, because the char array is `const`.

What the algorithm does is, it fills a char array with numbers ranging from -1 to 7, where, starting at 1, every number is inserted twice as often as the one before. That can be done with two simple nested loops, or one loop, `pow` and `memset`. But for that to work, the char array mustn't be const.

Comment: **–1** “You can't do that using loops, because the char array is `const`” is wrong (in the fair interpretation sense) or right but meaningless (in the completely literal sense). The final assertion “But for that to work, the char array mustn't be const” is Just Wrong™.

Answer (score 0):

The position of the `#define` preprocessor directive doesn't matter *technically* except that it comes before use of the `LT` macro that it defines. More coventional formatting would place it before the array definition. It's not limited to the scope it's defined in: *macros don't respect scopes*.

To define the array without using a macro you can use a singleton, such as a Meyers' singleton.

One-time initialization is the job of a constructor, so that's how I'd do it, a Meyers' singleton with a class type object whose constructor computes the array item values:

```
auto logarithms()
    -> std::array<signed char, 256> const&
{
    struct Wrapper
    {
        std::array<signed char, 256> items_;

        static void append( int const n, int const value, signed char*& p )
        {
            for( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) { *p++ = value; }
        }

        Wrapper()
        {
            items_[0] = -1;
            signed char* p = &items_[1];
            for( int i = 0; i < 8; ++i ) { append( 1 << i, i, p ); }
            assert( p == &*items_.end() );
        }
    };

    static Wrapper const the_array;
    return the_array.items_;
}
```

Note the use of explicit `signed char`: the type `char` is *not* guaranteed to be signed, i.e. to be able to represent that `-1` value.

However, in calculations each `signed char` value will be promoted and that can impair instead of improve efficiency. Using `signed char` is also just a complication. So unless this is for an embedded system with extremely little memory available, I'd use just `int` instead of `signed char`.

Comment: Alf This is a good answer to my problem. But wouldnt it be better if i would just allocate the array dynamically instead of using the built in std::array?

Comment: @MuhammadAliQadri: For a static size constant array, almost regardless of size,  dynamic allocation (i.e. using `std::vector`) is only a useless overhead. This is the kind of thing `std::array` is there for. Space for this array is in the program's loaded image.

Comment: Instead of a `std::array` you can just use a built-in raw array, but then the return type specification gets a little bit intricate, `-> signed char const (&)[256]`. And even more ungrokable with the C++03 function declaration syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use `constexpr` which can be called when a `constexpr` object is initialized. Filling arrays is possible, but `std::array` is missing some `constexpr` declarations which will be introduced with `C++17`. Right now, we have to resort to a plain array and then convert this to a `std::array` with a helper function `to_array` that will also be added to the standard/tr2.

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

// this is from cppreference

namespace detail {
template <class T, std::size_t N, std::size_t... I>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N>
    to_array_impl(T (&a)[N], std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return { {a[I]...} };
}
}

template <class T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<std::remove_cv_t<T>, N> to_array(T (&a)[N])
{
    return detail::to_array_impl(a, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

constexpr auto make()
{
    int a[256] = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,};

    for(size_t i=4, n=16, start=16; i <= 7; ++i, n *= 2)
    {
        for(size_t j=0; j != n; ++j)
        {
            a[start + j] = i;
        }

        start += n;
    }

    return to_array(a);
}

int main() {
    static const int LogTable256[256] = 
{
 #define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
 -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
 LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
 LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
};

    auto constexpr a = make();
    assert( std::equal( std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(LogTable256) ) );    
    return 0;
}
```

`auto constexpr a = make()` ensures that the table is compile-time value. A `auto const a = make()` does also work, but may not be evaluated at compile-time.

A simpler implementation is to use a class with a `costexpr` constructor that holds the table. The computation is fully compile-time.

```
class LogTable
{
public:
    constexpr LogTable()
    {
        for(size_t i=4, n=16, start=16; i <= 7; ++i, n *= 2)
        {
            for(size_t j=0; j != n; ++j)
            {
                a[start + j] = i;
            }

            start += n;
        }
    }

    constexpr int operator[](size_t i) const
    {
        return a[i];
    }
private:
    int a[256] = {-1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,};
};

int main() {
    static const int LogTable256[256] = 
    {
     #define LT(n) n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n, n
     -1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
     LT(4), LT(5), LT(5), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6), LT(6),
     LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7), LT(7)
    };

    LogTable constexpr l;
    for(auto i=0; i != 256; ++i)
    {
        assert(LogTable256[i] == l[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are two main problems here: (1) that the code doesn't compile with Visual C++ 2015, because it's very C++14-specific code, and (2) the copying, which I'm not sure will necessarily be optimized away. With that as the costs, this approach buys the ability to use the logarithms in compile time expressions. I don't think I would have made that trade. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't check VC++, just gcc 6.1. I think the copying can be avoided by creating a `constexpr` class that initializes the table in the constructor. This may also compile with VC++.

Comment: Well I'm upvoting for the effort to present this kind of code. I just wish Visual C++ would accept it at this time. Maybe it does, I'm only at update 2 and I think I read there's already an update 5.

Comment: (Main reason that there was evil phone-home potential introduced in update 3, that is, equipping the produced executables with that, so I stopped updating. I wish Microsoft wasn't run by the dark side!)